# Visual Studio 2010, 2015 - windows off screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I was previously using a dual-monitor setup with a 24" monitor and my laptop's built-in monitor.

I've since connected a 2nd 24" monitor and am no longer using the laptop screen at all. (It is disabled).

In my regular view (coding, etc) the properties window, solution explorer, toolbox, etc were all visible and I just needed to move/resize them to fit the larger screen size.

Unfortunately this is no the case with the debugging view. I need to debug something and it appears my locals and other windows are off the edge of the screen. I've tried Ctrl+D,L but it doesn't seem to want to bring it up.

I can't find anywhere in the menu a command to reset windows.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I've confirmed this problem can still happen in VS 2015; the accepted answer works there too.

Comment: Happened in VS 2017; the accepted answer worked :)

Comment: And VS2019; the accepted answer still works!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can move any window in Windows using keyboard shortcuts. First, give the focus to the window, even if you can't see it, by toggling the tool window. Then press alt+space, 'm', press an arrow key, and then move the cursor in the visible screen region. If all goes well, the window should have followed. You can practice the trick with a notepad window. Note that the mnemonic depends on your Windows language, it's 'l' in French.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I did know about the move function but didn't know you could bring the menu up with alt+space. I usually right-click the title bar, or the icon in the taskbar. I can debug again! Thanks :)

Comment: Excellent! I had Launchy set up (default shortcut Alt + Space) which is why I had trouble fixing it.  Once I'd changed the Launchy shortcut this worked.

Comment: This fix also works in Visual Studio 2015 running in Windows 10.

Comment: Then press alt+space, 'm', press an arrow key, and then move the cursor in the visible screen region. !!!! MERCI BEAUCOUP  That was magic sauce.

Comment: In VS-2017 if for some reason you can't move the window, try maximizing it from the `alt-space` context menu.

Comment: Still works in VS2019, thanks!

Comment: I came here because I was facing this issue but found that using that shortcut brings up the `PowerToys Run` instead, anyway around this short of removing or reassigning the default shortcut for that?

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried the Window menu | Reset Window Layout command?  Obviously that will do more than you really want, but it is perhaps better than nothing

Comment: In my case the Find/Replace box disappeared. Alt-Space doesn't work as it triggers the menu of the main VS window instead. Reset layout did the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately this and the above don't help with the Perforce Login window that's stuck off screen. Help.

Answer (score 3):

This phenomena of off-screen dialog windows appears to coincide with having dual monitors as OP indicates.  I resolved my issue be disconnecting the dual monitors and bringing Visual Studio up on the main monitor.  I summoned the offending dialog and I was able to access it again.  Manually recenter the dialog otherwise this does not work.  Reattach the dual monitor and the dialog works properly thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will reset Window settings, but you could try deleting your .suo file (in solution directory). This might reset those windows to their default positions.

Comment: This reset the location of the floating Exception Info dialogue which had mysteriously decided to go for flight in the clouds...

Comment: Bringing Exception info to order is such a relief! Halleluyah! :)

Comment: This is an issue if you check this into source control. For example person x has a higher res monitor then you. They move the window to the edge of their screen. They save the settings into ther `.suo` file and check it in. You pull this and the screen isn't visible to you. This is almost certainly the underlying issue in a lot of these cases

Comment: Agreed @Liam - an ignore on .suo files should be added to the source control filter and remove these from source.

Answer (score 1):

This should still be an issue. Here is my simple solution.

- Remove the following file. ('user' and 'MyApps' in my case, yours could be different.)

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MyApps\window-state.json
- Restart the application.

<><

Answer (score 0):

A small update: I'm using a freshly-installed Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 box (long story) and the "Find in Files" dialog was off-screen. Alt-m does not work (it brings up the "Magnify" dialog). Instead right-click the windows taskbar and choose "Cascade Windows" to bring the dialog back on to the screen.